# Trouble with passing variables in functions

Tags: python, function, variables

So I'm making a music player in python  but I'm having trouble when passing variables into my function and I get this error message:

```
TypeError: next() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I've searched on google for an anwser but their programmes and solutions were to different for me to understand how it works and why it works. Anyway here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import pygame
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from time import sleep
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Music Player Alpha")
        AutoPlay = True
        Play = True
        SongQueue = []
        Song = os.listdir('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/' )
        Song = sorted(Song)
        CurrentSong = 0
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/' + Song[0])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btnQuit = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit", self)
        btnQuit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        btnPlay = QtGui.QPushButton("Play", self)
        btnPlay.clicked.connect(self.play)
        btnPlay.move(100, 100)
        btnPause = QtGui.QPushButton("Pause", self)
        btnPause.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        btnPause.move(200, 100)
        btnNext = QtGui.QPushButton("Next", self)
        btnNext.clicked.connect(self.next)
        btnNext.move(300, 100)
        btnPrevious = QtGui.QPushButton("Previous", self)
        btnPrevious.clicked.connect(self.previous)
        btnPrevious.move(0, 100)
        self.show()

    def close(self):
        print("Closing application")
        sys.exit()

    def play(self, Play):
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        Play = True

    def pause(self, Play):
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        play = False

    def next(self, CurrentSong, Song):
        print("1")
        CurrentSong = CurrentSong + 1
        if CurrentSong > len(Song) + 1:
            CurrentSong = 0
            pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/' + Song[CurrentSong])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/' + Song[CurrentSong])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

    def previous(self, CurrentSong, Song):
        CurrentSong = CurrentSong - 1
        if CurrentSong < 0:
            CurrentSong = len(Song) -1
            pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/' + Song[CurrentSong])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/' + Song[CurrentSong])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: show your function call

Comment: Your `btnNext.clicked` event handler is calling `self.next` with no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a call is defined:

```
btnNext.clicked.connect(self.next)
```

So when the button is clicked you run `self.next(mouse_event)` This is the function signature:

```
def next(self, CurrentSong, Song):
```

So when a button is clicked you send two parameters: `self`, from the `self.next`, and an `event` which has nothing to do with songs, it has info on the click. You were expecting 3 parameters `self,CurrentSong,Song`, and not an `event` - so two mistakes. A workaround is to not accept parameters besides self to next, and save the current song in the class:

```
def next(self,event):
    currentSong = self.currentSong
```

etc... If you want to forego the event you can lambda hide it:

```
btnNext.clicked.connect(lambda e:self.next)
```

and change `next` accordingly.